# Android: Listview on fragmvent, set image from url

Tags: android, android-bitmap

How to update ListViev with image from url

To download image I'm using:

**downloadImage**

```
public static Bitmap downloadImage(String iUrl) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    BufferedInputStream buf_stream = null;
    try {
        Log.v(TAG, "Starting loading image by URL: " + iUrl);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(iUrl).openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.connect();
        buf_stream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream(), 8192);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf_stream);
        buf_stream.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        buf_stream = null;
        conn = null;
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Url parsing was failed: " + iUrl);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, iUrl + " does not exists");
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Out of memory!!!");
        return null;
    } finally {
        if ( buf_stream != null )
            try { buf_stream.close(); } catch (IOException ex) {}
        if ( conn != null )
            conn.disconnect();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

My ListView listen when button clicked, and then update ListView

```
 try{
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("items");
                            //JSONArray Data = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("snippet");
                        for(int i = 0; i<jsonMainNode.length();i++){

                            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                            String name = jsonChildNode.optString("kind");
                            String number = jsonChildNode.optString("etag");


                            JSONObject item = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject snippet = item.getJSONObject("snippet");

                            String title = snippet.getString("title");
                            String channelTitle = snippet.getString("channelTitle");
                            String pubDate = snippet.getString("publishedAt");

                            JSONObject thumbs = snippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails");
                            JSONObject thumb = thumbs.getJSONObject("default");
                            final String ico = thumb.getString("url");



                            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {

                                    bmp = ImageManager.downloadImage(ico);

                                }
                            }).start();






                            countryList.add(createEmployee(title,channelTitle,pubDate, bmp));
                        }

simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

ListView Updting, but without image. If Im using Image from @drawable all its ok.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the bitmap hasn't finished being downloaded before you try to use it. When you call `start()` on a thread instance, that method returns immediately on the thread it was called on, while the new thread goes off and executes the `run` method (its own or that of the `Runnable` provided as a constructor parameter).

As `start()` returns immediately, you go straight on to create the employee before the bitmap has downloaded. As a result, `bmp` is `null` and there's no image to display.

You need to set up your code so that once an image is downloaded it is set on the appropriate view.